# Android - obtener datos de un api

Tags: android, android-studio, api, retrofit

Buen día a todos, tengo un programa que estoy conectando a unos servicios web, pero de todos los que me despliega, quiero obtener unos cuantos pero me arroja NULO.

Esta es mi interfaz

/

```
/api para obtener la información del usuarios
@Multipart
@POST("get-user-data?")
Call<UserDataProfile> userdataprofile(
    @Query("access_token") String token,//hacemos la consulta dinamica porque debemos enviar el access token junto a la URL
    @Part("server_key") RequestBody key,
    @Part("fetch") RequestBody userData,
    @Part("user_id") RequestBody userId
```

Esta es mi clase UserDataProfile

```
//Constructores
public UserDataProfile(String server_key, String fetch, String user_id) {
    this.server_key = server_key;
    this.fetch = fetch;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

//Getters and setters

public String getApi_status() {
    return api_status;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

  public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}


public String getWorking() {
    return working;
}


public String getFollowing_count() {
    return following_count;
}


public String getFollowers_count() {
    return followers_count;
}
```

}

y esta es la respuesta que tengo, pero no se como extraer los datos de username, email, etc que estan dentro del corchete de "user_data"

```
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:     "api_status": 200,
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:     "user_data": {
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:         "user_id": "27",
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:         "username": "Admin5555",
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:         "email": "danielc36@otmail.com",
2020-05-27 00:38:30.838 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:         "first_name": "Eduardo",
2020-05-27 00:38:30.839 10836-10904/com.example.anika D/OkHttp:         "last_name": "Gaytan"
}
```

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Si tienes un callback al consultar tu API agregalo por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar en tu clase `UserDataProfile` la anotaciòn `@SerializedName` a los campos para que de esta forma mapees los valores del json a los campos de tu objeto al obtener la respuesta, ejemplo:

```
@SerializedName("api_status")
@Expose
private String api_status;

@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String first_name;

@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String last_name;


//Constructores
public UserDataProfile(String server_key, String fetch, String user_id) {
    this.server_key = server_key;
    this.fetch = fetch;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

//Getters and setters

public String getApi_status() {
    return api_status;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

  public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}


public String getWorking() {
    return working;
}


public String getFollowing_count() {
    return following_count;
}


public String getFollowers_count() {
    return followers_count;
}
```